# Writing complex number $c$ in form $e^{iz}$

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation

Let $c\in \mathbb C$. Then we can write $c = r\cdot e^{i\varphi},$ where $\varphi\in [0,2\pi)$ and $r\in [0, \infty)$.

My professor stated, however, that if $z \in \mathbb C$, then $c = e^{i\cdot z}$ holds as well, i.e., there exists a representation for $c$ in the "pure" form $c = e^{iz}$ with $z\in \mathbb C$, even though the modulus of $c$, i.e. $|c|$, might be different from $1$. Could sb please prove this?

Thanks!

Comment: How about $z=\varphi-i\ln(r)$?

Comment: Let $z=x+iy$; what's $e^z$?

Comment: Excluding the case $c=0$ (which was probably intended), this is an immediate consequence of the fact that $z\mapsto iz$ is a surjection $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ and the fact that $z\mapsto e^z$ is a surjection $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: This $i$ in $e^{iz}$ seems unnecessary and pointless.  There isn't much point in *doing* this in my opinion but we *defined* $e^z;z\in \mathbb C$ so that $e^{z+w}=e^ze^w$ and $[e^z]' = e^z$ and as such we *have* to have $e^{z}=e^{Re(z)+iIm(z)}=[e^{Re(z)}] *e^{iIm(z)}$ where $e^{Re(z)}$ is a *positive* (non-zero) real number. And $e^{iIm(z)}$ is a complex number of magnitude $1$.

Comment: @fleablood Could you please reformat your comment?

Comment: Yeah... I can't preview a comment until *after* I submit so....

Comment: @fleablood: When I write a comment as splendidly MathJaxed as yours, I preview it in the Answer window to save me having to edit it 20 times. (And occasionally I post it as an answer by mistake...)

Comment: I do that occasionally but in general I just want to get a comment started and then a bit needs Jaxing and then a little more and....

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? I mean, I didn't choose to write $e^{iz}$, this is done in our lecture and in the literature, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if $r \ne 0$.

Then  $r*e^{i\phi} = e^{\ln r}e^{i\phi} = e^{\ln r + i\phi} = e^{i\frac {\ln r+ i\phi}i}$ for $z = \frac {\ln r+ i\phi}i$ if you want.

This assumes we are allowing $e^z= e^{Re(z) + iIm(z)} = e^{Re(z)}e^{iIm(z)}=e^{Re(z)}(\cos (Im(z)) + i\sin (Im(z)))$ to be true by fiat definition.

Which we are.

Comment: Perfect, it is a nice answer!